# Break the time series dataframe into one has multiple variables each one has the name of the year

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have the following time series dateframe:

```
       date_time                     system_load
0     2013-01-01 00:00:00.000000     599.2
1     2013-01-01 00:59:59.999999     759.2
2     2013-01-01 02:00:00.000001     954.5
3     2013-01-01 03:00:00.000000     190.9
4     2013-01-01 03:59:59.999999     465.2
...                          ...     ...
70123 2020-12-31 18:59:59.999999     355.9
70124 2020-12-31 20:00:00.000001     752.1
70125 2020-12-31 21:00:00.000000     928.5
70126 2020-12-31 21:59:59.999999     299.2
70127 2020-12-31 23:00:00.000001     478.5
```

What I want is a new dataframe as below :

```
       Year2013     Year 2014   Year2015     Year2016   Year2017     Year2018   Year2019     Year 2020
0      599.2           ...       ...           ...       ...           ...       ...          355.9                                                                           
1      759.2           ...       ...           ...       ...           ...       ...          752.1  
2      954.5           ...       ...           ...       ...           ...       ...          928.5
3      190.9           ...       ...           ...       ...           ...       ...          299.2
4      465.2           ...       ...           ...       ...           ...       ...          478.5
...    ...             ...       ...           ...       ...           ...       ...          ...                                
8760   ...             ....      ...           ...       ...           ...       ...          ...
8761   NaN             NaN       NaN           ...       NaN           NaN        NaN         ...
...    NaN             NaN       NaN           ...       NaN           NaN        NaN         ...                   
8784   NaN             NaN       NaN           ...       NaN           NaN        NaN         ...
```

and the leap Years taken into considerations.
Any help to get what *I want*
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm supposing you have this dataframe:

```
                     date_time  system_load
0   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000000        599.2
1   2013-01-01 00:59:59.999999        759.2
2   2013-01-01 02:00:00.000001        954.5
3   2013-01-01 03:00:00.000000        190.9
4   2013-01-01 03:59:59.999999        465.2
5   2020-12-31 18:59:59.999999        355.9
6   2020-12-31 20:00:00.000001        752.1
7   2020-12-31 21:00:00.000000        928.5
8   2020-12-31 21:59:59.999999        299.2
9   2020-12-31 23:00:00.000001        478.5
10  2020-12-31 23:00:01.000001        400.0
```

Then:

```
df["date_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date_time"])
df["year"] = df["date_time"].dt.year
df["index"] = df.groupby("year").transform("cumcount")

print(
    df.pivot(columns="year", index="index", values="system_load").add_prefix(
        "Year"
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
year   Year2013  Year2020
index                    
0         599.2     355.9
1         759.2     752.1
2         954.5     928.5
3         190.9     299.2
4         465.2     478.5
5           NaN     400.0
```